# Window application for first time use

Tags: c#-4.0

In, my window application I had made all functionality, and all are working fine, now I was thinking that user have to enter **password** to start  application, and this I had done very easily by entering **user id** and **password** in to DB directly, but now I am little bit afraid, that if the user is opening application **first time** and in first time there will be no any logging authentication details available, and so, I think that if user opening application first time, that user have to enter its user id and password, which will be use for log in authentication...

Answer (score 1):

You can use application setting for this, see below code....

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.IsFirstTimeUse)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.IsFirstTimeUse = false;
}
```

Hope you like this solution...